# Espresso, Find dialog and dismiss it

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-dialogfragment, android-dialog, ui-testing

I tried to find a dialog cancel button and push it in Espresso UI Testing, but I couldn't.

This is my code.

```
onView(withId(R.id.dialog_close_button)).check(matches(isDisplayed()))
```

What is the best solution for it?

Please comment your opinion.

Comment: Can you post your xml of your dialog?

Comment: implementation 'androidx.biometric:biometric:1.0.0-beta02'

Comment: please check this blog about the specific dialog https://medium.com/exploring-android/exploring-android-p-fingerprint-dialog-fa672ae62c6f

Answer (score 2):

If you use the UI-Automator with AndroidX, you can find the dialog and buttons.

It is a gradle dependency code.

```
dependencies {
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.uiautomator:uiautomator:2.2.0'
}
```

You can reach the button with this code.

It is Kotlin code.

```
val cancel = activityTestRule.activity.getString(R.string.dialog_cancel_button)
val button = UiDevice
    .getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation())
    .findObject(
        UiSelector()
            .text(cancel.toUpperCase())
            .text(cancel)
    )
if (button.exists() && button.isEnabled) {
    button.click()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's an Android dialog and you use two buttons you can find the view using:

```
onView.withId(android.R.id.button1).perform(ViewActions.click()) //Click on accept button
onView.withId(android.R.id.button2).perform(ViewActions.click()) //Click on cancel button
```

If you want to test if they are visible you want to use:

```
assert onView.withId(android.R.id.button1).check(matches(ViewMatchers.isDisplayed()))
```

Then if you don't want the android one, just replace the id's for yours and it should work, remember **if you have duplicated ID's it will complain**

### EDIT

I suggest to use [`Layout Inspector`](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector), so you can find the ID of each component of your screen so you can replace it with the old answer.

So the steps are :

1. Open the app and find that dialog
2. Then go to `Tools` > `Layout Inspector` > Choose your processor
3. Click on the item you want to click with `Espresso`
4. Replace it in your `onView.withId(HERE_GOES_THE_ID)...`

Comment: It the dialog is a special case such as Biometric dialog, this code can't reach the dialog.

Comment: Could you post your XML or a picture of your dialog?

Comment: @hyungjunyoo Have you solved this? In order to help other people if this helped you feel free to upvote and mark this as a correct answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You should add the [RootMatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/matcher/RootMatchers) `isDialog()` to match Roots that are dialogs (i.e. is not a window of the currently resumed activity).

And also don't forget to perform click on that button if you want to dismiss the dialog as you said in the title.

Use this code:

```
onView(withId(R.id.dialog_close_button))
    .inRoot(isDialog())
    .check(matches(isDisplayed()))
    .perform(click());
```